# Spring Integration - Configuring Transaction Timeout on Splitter output channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a splitter which outputs to a taskexecutor backed channel. The idea is to process all of those messages in parallel. Recently we started seeing Txn timeout for some of those messages. What's the best way to increase Txn timeout with minimal changes ? Here is the relevant configuration code piece.

```
....
....
<channel id="splitterOutputChannel">
    <dispatcher task-executor="eventProcessingExecutor" failover="false" />
</channel>

<splitter id="listSplitter" input-channel="splitterInputChannel" output-channel="splitterOutputChannel" />

<service-activator ref="referenceBean" method="setFileId" input-channel="splitterOutputChannel"
    output-channel="eventProcessingInputChannel" />

<chain input-channel="eventProcessingInputChannel" output-channel="enricherOutputRouterChannel">
    <header-enricher error-channel="errorHandlingChannel" />
    <service-activator ref="messageEnricherBean" method="getPayloadFromDatabase" />
</chain>
....
....
```

Will setting Txn timeout on the method setFileId work out ? 
(Currently, there is no Transaction configuration on it, and spring takes default weblogic 30 sec timeout)

```
@Transactional(timeout=60)
public Message<?> setFileId(Message<?> message) {
    ...
    return myMessage;
}
```

Comment: You need to show a stack trace. I presume you realize that the async handoff at the task executor will terminate the transaction as soon as the last split is queued in the TE. Nothing downstream of that channel will participate in the transaction.

Comment: I should have been more elaborate:
1. Yea, I am aware of the Txn boundaries.
2. I can't paste the complete stack trace, but we have some heavy lifting being done after the splitting. That includes DB updates, couple of WS calls, MQ interactions to name a few. The timeout happens during one of the DB reads, which happens early in the flow.
    SEVERE: Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection java.sql.SQLException: Transaction rolled back: Transaction timed out after 30 seconds 
BEA1-752F7C3077AA4B2010ED
at XXXIngTransactionDAOImpl.getXXXINGLogByTxnId(XXX.java:60)

Comment: getXXXINGLogByTxnId method has "@"Transactional attribute, but I dont want to touch/change that as its a common method. So the question really is, if I put @Transactional annotation early in the flow during setFileId operation with timeout of 60 sec, is that correct place to do that ? If yes, I think all transactional updates/calls within that thread context (I am using DirectChannels everywhere after the splitter) should honor that original timeout.

Comment: No. That's why I need a stack trace. The tx will commit when setField exits. You need to wrap the whole downstream flow in a tx. One way would be to advise send on eventProcessingInputChannel with a transaction advice.

Comment: Thanks Gary, now when you said I realized why my solution wont work. Not sure what I was thinking writing what I wrote. Let me work on the advice configuration and respond soon here. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Gary, how does this look :

        <aop:config>  
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="eventProcessingChannelSendAdvice" pointcut="bean(eventProcessingInputChannel )" />  
 </aop:config>  

 
 <tx:advice id="eventProcessingChannelSendAdvice" transaction-manager="eventProcessingTxnManager">  
  <tx:attributes>  
   <tx:method name="send"/>  
  </tx:attributes>  
 </tx:advice>  

 
 <beans:bean id="eventProcessingTxnManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager">  
  <beans:property name="defaultTimeout" value="90"/>  
 </beans:bean>